# CASE statement for insert, update or delete

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

I have create on Stored Procedure. In that Stored Proc i want case statement for insert, update or delete.

```
If v_var='I' then insert into main_tbl
If v_var='D' then delete from main_tbl where  <condition>
If v_var='U' then update main_tbl set <condition>.
```

So for that i have created Stored Proc

```
create or replace procedure sp_cs as
    v_var txt.col1%type;
    type record is ref cursor return txt%rowtype;  --Staging table
    v_rc record;
    cursor c1 is select * from txt;
begin
    open c1;
    loop 
        fetch c1 into v_rc;
        for i in 1 .. v_rc.count
        loop
         select v_rc(i).col1 into v_var from txt;
            case when v_var ='I' then
                 insert into main_tbl values (v_rc(i).col1, .....);
            when v_var ='D' then
                 delete from main_tbl m where m.col2=v_rc(i).col2;
            when v_var ='U' then
                 update main_tbl m set m.col2=v_rc(i).col2;
            end case;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    close c1;
end;
```

After executing this the data has not able to load into the **main_tbl**. Could you please help me resolve my issue.
Thanks

Comment: The `when` keyword is missing, twice. And an `end` too.

Comment: @jarlh I have done but still getting same issue.

Comment: Is `create or replace sp_cs` actually `create or replace procedure sp_cs as` in your real code?

Comment: The loop never exits, as there is no `exit when c1%notfound` to check the cursor status (though a normal [Cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html) would make this a lot simpler). Also `v_var` is never set to any value. Also, `v_rc` is a record not an array, so there cannot be any `v_rc.count` or `v_rc(i)`.

Comment: You didn't set any value for v_var. In this case it will be null by default. So case statement never satisfied.

Comment: @Gaj Please check the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the **`OPEN..FETCH..LOOP`** has become pretty old-fashioned. You should simply use single insert/update/delete statement based on the parameter.It is going to be far more efficient than your looping constructs.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE sp_cs (p_var txt.col1%TYPE) 
IS 
BEGIN 
    CASE p_var 
      WHEN 'I' THEN 
        INSERT INTO main_tbl 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   txt; 
      WHEN 'D' THEN 
        DELETE FROM main_tbl m 
        WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   txt t 
                       WHERE  m.col2 = t.col2); 
      WHEN 'U' THEN 
        UPDATE main_tbl m 
        SET    m.col2 = (SELECT v_rc.col2 
                         FROM   txt 
                         WHERE  m.somecol = t.somecol); -- the column you want to compare while updating
    END CASE; 
END; 

/
```

While It is not clear from your update query what you are trying to achieve, I assume you have a common column in `txt` while updating col2 from `main_tbl`. Moreover, I have used your parameter as a procedure argument `p_var`. You may use it as local variable if you don't want to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your procedure as it is, so you're missing one keyword in the first line:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_cs
```

You're missing `WHEN` keywords and `END CASE`.

```
 case when v_var = 'I'
      then insert into main_tbl values (v_rc(i).col1, .....);
      when v_var = 'D'
      then delete from main_tbl m where m.col2=v_rc.col2;
      when v_var = 'U'
      then update main_tbl m set m.col2=v_rc.col2;
 end case;
```

Answer (score 0):

The create procedure has a couple of syntax errors, try with the below. 
Besides, have a look at [Oracle MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)

A MERGE would be able to do INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE in one single statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_cs
IS
   v_var   txt.col1%TYPE;

   TYPE record IS REF CURSOR
      RETURN txt%ROWTYPE;                                      --Staging table

   v_rc    record;

   CURSOR c1
   IS
      SELECT * FROM txt;
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;

   LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO v_rc;

      FOR i IN 1 .. v_rc.COUNT
      LOOP
         CASE
            WHEN v_var = 'I'
            THEN
               INSERT INTO main_tbl
                    VALUES (v_rc (i).col1);
            WHEN v_var = 'D'
            THEN
               DELETE FROM main_tbl m
                     WHERE m.col2 = v_rc.col2;
            WHEN v_var = 'U'
            THEN
               UPDATE main_tbl m
                  SET m.col2 = v_rc.col2;
         END CASE;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need ref cur here? If not then try this

```
create or replace procedure sp_cs 
as
    cursor c1 is select * from txt;
    rc c1%rowtype;
begin
    For c in rc Loop
        case c.col1 
            When 'I' Then
                insert into main_tbl values (c.col1, .....);
            When 'U' Then
                update main_tbl m set m.col2=c.col2;
            When 'D'
                delete from main_tbl m where m.col2=c.col2;
        End Case;
    End Loop;
end;
```